# Terminal Server: no default printer

Tags: printing, terminal

I have a customer with 3 2008 R2 Standard terminal servers in 1 TSfarm.

All clients are XP/Vista/7 Pro and login with a generic account automatically at startup.
After startup the latest mstsc client is started and asks for a login. The mstsc client is configured to not redirect printers.

The issue is as follows:

Sometimes users login and are not assigned a default printer. They can set one manually but next time they login, they have to set him as default again. And once in a while if they do have a default printer it's not the one they selected previous session.

Printers are added manually as needed by me or the user from a 2008 R2 file/print member server, not through a script. Brands are HP, Brother, Samsung & one Xerox. Some HP's use the universal printer driver, some a specific one for the model in question.

Scripting a default printer is kinda hard as users move throughout the building a lot.
Most of the time they disconnect the session instead of logging off, so a loginscript wouldn't run anyway at reconnect.

All users are non admins, have no special checkboxes marked in their AD account. There is no local printer on the TS, not even the XPS printer. On the TS the checkbox to disable printer redirection is not marked because some users login from home and need to print there.

Installing all printers locally on every TS is possible but the users would be very confused if they see all printers throughout the office in their session.

They had this problem already when they were running 2x 2008 Enterprise 32bit SP2.
I was hoping it would be fixed in R2 but it still occurs. :(

Anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stupid question, so please forgive me but when you say the users are logging in with a "generic account" do you mean they all share the same account, or they all share a uniquely different account by the same notation?

The only thing I could think of is restructuring the way you manage your users and assigning each person a generic, yet unique (user000, user001, etc.) account so that you can manage the default settings for each of their printers trough GPO.

You can segment each user to a group that will have X printers listed and have a specific printer defaulted. I apologize if this isn't what you're looking for or if I understood you incorrectly, here's a reference to what I was referring to:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/06/24/gp-preferences-set-a-default-printer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929270) the problem occurs if the following registry subkey is missing:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` if I'm reading your problem right. Check it out. it concerns 2003 Server but I would still check it for the 2008 you have.